# how to change people picker value in infopath form after every form updating

Tags: infopath, peoplepicker

I have a state machine workflow and related task. Task can be edited until it satisfy some conditions. Task formed by infopath. These task contains one people picker field. I assign 3 fields with these values:

```
private void createTask_Operator_MethodInvoking(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 this.createTask_Id = Guid.NewGuid(); 

 this.createTask_Properties.ExtendedProperties["ows_TaskDisplayName"] = "user1";
 this.createTask_Properties.ExtendedProperties["ows_TaskAccountId"] = @"SP\user1";
 this.createTask_Properties.ExtendedProperties["ows_TaskAccountType"] = "User"; 
}
```

It is works, I can see in my form value these user. But when I change the user(for example: "user2") and submit the form, I cannot retrieve my manually changed field value, it always returns values of "user1".

```
private void onTaskChanged_Operator_Invoked(object sender, ExternalDataEventArgs e)
{
  this.onTaskChanged_AfterProperties = this.onTaskChanged.AfterProperties;
  this.onTaskChanged_BeforeProperties = this.onTaskChanged.BeforeProperties;

  // here I cannot retrieve changed field value, always returns: SP\user1
  this.workflowProperties.Item["UserName"] = 
      this.onTaskChanged_AfterProperties.ExtendedProperties["TaskAccountId"].ToString();
  this.workflowProperties.Item.Update();
}
```

Please, if you faced such problem, help me with that...

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a little trouble understanding your problem, but here are two answers. To successfully set the value of a people picker field, you have to correctly populate all three fields: DisplayName, AccountId, and AccountType. AccountType is always "User", but the other two have to align with your AD or wherever you're getting your user data from. To get data from a people picker, the best solution often includes [the double eval trick](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2006/04/05/569338.aspx): `eval(eval(person, "concat(my:AccountId, ';')"), "..")` This handles multiple entries correctly, if you mean that you're only getting the first in the list.

Comment: Then I'm not quite sure what's causing your problem. Perhaps it's appending user2 instead of overwriting user1. The user properties (DisplayName, AccountId, and AccountType) exist per person, so maybe you're only selecting data from person[0]. I have no experience with this, though, so hopefully someone more knowledgeable will answer.